# Undefined personalization strings and AMP variables from an email using SSJS on a microsite page

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, microsites

I'm trying to use SSJS on a microsite landing page to pull in  personalization strings and variables from an email. I tried using both the MicrositeURL() AMPscript function and the microsite_base_url personalization string as the account I'm working on is not 2.0.

The result of the below code are variables that are undefined.

Relevant email code:

```
    <body>
%%[
VAR @var

SET @var = 1
]%%
<br><br>
Microsite URL: <a href="%%=MicrositeURL(825318)=%%" >this</a>
<br>
Microsite_base_url: <a href="%%microsite_base_url[default]825318[/default]%%" >this</a> 

</body>
```

Here is the SSJS on the microsite page:

```
<script runat="server" language="javascript">
    Platform.Load('Core', '1');

    var subscriberkey = Variable.GetValue('_subscriberkey');
    var emailaddress = Variable.GetValue('emailaddr');
    var jobid = Variable.GetValue('jobid');
    var batchid = Variable.GetValue('_JobSubscriberBatchID');
    var listid = Variable.GetValue('listid');
    var istestsend = Variable.GetValue('_IsTestSend');
    var optoutflag = Variable.GetValue('@optoutflag');
</script>

<body>    
<p>
       SubscriberKey: <ctrl:var name=subscriberkey /><br>
       EmailAddress: <ctrl:var name=emailaddress /><br>
       JobID: <ctrl:var name=jobid /><br>
       BatchID: <ctrl:var name=batchid /><br>
       ListID: <ctrl:var name=listid /><br>
       IsTestSend: <ctrl:var name=istestsend /><br>
       OptOutFlag: <ctrl:var name=optoutflag /><br>
                             </p>
</body>
```

The body of the landing page spits out "undefined" for the variables.

```
SubscriberKey: undefined
EmailAddress: undefined
JobID: undefined
BatchID: undefined
ListID: undefined
IsTestSend: undefined
OptOutFlag: undefined
```

I am able to pull in these variables with AMPscript, so I may need to use AMP instead of SSJS if I can't figure this out.

Please help! Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be using the [**Attribute.GetValue()**](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/content/server_side_javascript/server_side_javascript_syntax_guide/core_library_server_side_javascript_functions/recipient_server_side_javascript_functions/) function to retrieve the personalization string values:

```
<script runat="server" language="javascript">
    Platform.Load('Core', '1');

    var subscriberkey = Attribute.GetValue('_subscriberkey');
    var emailaddress = Attribute.GetValue('emailaddr');
    var jobid = Attribute.GetValue('jobid');
    var batchid = Attribute.GetValue('_JobSubscriberBatchID');
    var listid = Attribute.GetValue('listid');
    var istestsend = Attribute.GetValue('_IsTestSend');
    var optoutflag = Variable.GetValue('@optoutflag');
</script>
```

I have a [**custom preference center boilerplate**](https://gist.github.com/wvpv/19777e1167d6ac91e2e8) that you might find helpful.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, Adam. I made the updates and can now get the personalization strings to come through. However, still having issues with the variables. Both of the following are coming up as undefined: `Variable.GetValue("@optoutflag")` and `Request.GetQueryStringParameter("optoutflag")`

Comment: `Variable.GetValue()` is for retrieving AMPScript variables previously set, and `Request.GetQueryStringParameter()` is for retrieving URL parameters.  Based on your example, you don't need either of those, just `Attribute.getValue()`, since the sending DE columns (and Profile Attributes) are present via the `QS` parameter in your microsite URL.